# How Do You Load An Image into A PowerPoint Template Using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ms-office, powerpoint

I know it's possible but I"m new to it.  How do you create new powerpoint slides with an outside image/title/footer/whatever?  Basically I just want to send an image path and load it into a brand new presentation, save it off, and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at [Office Development with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430) to get you started. There might be more PowerPoint samples in the [Previous Versions section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133431)